# Stop the installshield installation if a file is not found in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, events, installation, installshield

The aim of the question is to stop an installshield installation once it has started installing the service.

In particular, I want to stop the installation if a file *file.txt* is not found in the selected directory (the user will select the installation path).

To control that, I'm calling the `BeforeInstall` event from `ServiceInstaller`.

```
Private Sub ServiceInstaller1_BeforeInstall(sender As Object, e As InstallEventArgs) Handles ServiceInstaller1.BeforeInstall
    Dim filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).Replace("\", "\\")
    If Not File.Exists(filePath) & "\file.txt" Then
        MsgBox("The specified file is not found in that path, the installation will stop.")
        'Missing code
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tried with `End`, `Exit`, and many others but no one stops the installation.

Comment: You may wanna show a `Dialog` and then decide to close the installshield bay calling something like `return 0` in your program

Comment: What kind of dialog? How can I do that? Please explain it a little bit more.

Comment: A `Dialog` window, a common way to notify users perhaps by decision like adding OK or Cancel buttons.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I mean, with that dialog window, how can I stop the installation doing a rollback?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you can show the not found file likely by a `Dialog` and call the `RoleBack` method which rolls back service application information written to the registry by the installation procedure. This method is meant to be used by installation tools, which process the appropriate methods automatically. (Overrides `Installer.Rollback(IDictionary)`).

To be aware of `ServiceInstaller` methods see [The MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller_methods%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). And for using `RollBack` method, See [This MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.rollback%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which remarks :

> When you override the `Rollback` method in a derived class, be sure to
>   call the base class's `Rollback` method first in your derived method. A
>   rollback operation restores the computer to the state it was in before
>   the installations occurred.

Comment: I see... And how can I take the state of the moment before the installation?I have to use IDictionary? How can I use it?

Comment: @Asa Oh my mistake :( I entered the link twice (redundantly). Check the second link in my answer which refers to another page now.

Comment: @Asa You can't Access `savedState` before installation! Since it belongs to class! `public override void Rollback(
 IDictionary savedState
)`